# Is it possible to add interceptors programmatically in ejbs?

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0, java-ee-6

We are developing an enterprise application. All services will be exposed as Restful web services. The business logic is written in ejbs. We have to call many backend systems from the ejbs. The backends are again web services exposed from various applications/teams in our organization.

Below is a simple flow

WS1 <-> BL_EJB1 <-> BE_EJB1

Where WS is web service, BL is business logic and BE is back end.

We persist the whole transaction in tables called reporting_stats and failure_stats. They basically contains the user details such as user id, time when the request came in, time when the response has been sent, path of the web service that has been called, name of the backend that has been called from the business logic, status of the backend call such as how much time was taken to get the response from the backend, was the response from the backend successful etc.

As this logging is common for each and every service, we introduced interceptors to log the transaction details in the tables. The interceptor and the ejbs exchanges data through EjbContext. Below is the modified flow

WS1 <-> Interceptor(BL_EJB1) <-> Interceptor(BE_EJB1)

There are some situations where we have to call BL_EJB1 and BL_EJB2 from BL_EJB3. In this case we dont want the Interceptors on BL_EJB1 and BL_EJB2 to be triggered.

Is there any way to introduce interceptors at runtime instead of annotating the method during development?

Comment: what about an additional layer in your application (instead of or in addition to using interceptors)? WS1 calls the higher facade layer where logging etc is done, Higher facade layer calls method from lower layer where the actual business logic is done. Other services from the lower layer may call each other without getting through the higher facade layer then.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to add interceptors at runtime, in `ProcessAnnotatedType`-Phase (see eg [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34474592/4308751) SO-question). But as far as I understand your problem you want to toggle an interceptor per ejb call.

Before bypassing an interceptor I would rethink the benefits it gives to my code. It not only adds some functionality, it also documents it. Whenever a method is annotated eg by `@LogTransactionDetails`, then it should be absolutely clear that your transaction details *are* logged. Whenever you work around this with some runtime-magic it will be confusing some month, weeks, days later.

So I would prefer an additional layer as stg suggested. It will clarify your code and your business boundaries.

But if this is no option in your usecase: You are already using `EJBContext` in your interceptors. You can add an additional flag `NoNeedForLogging` in `EJBContext#getContextData()` while calling BL_EJB3,  and refer to it in your interceptors using `InvocationContext#getContextData()`.