# How to add a EJB Interceptor programmatically?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, wildfly, cdi

I'm trying to add a Interceptor in a EJB at runtime programmatically via CDI extensions.

This EJB exposes a Remote interface for remote calls. But I'm trying to add this Interceptor in the implementation class of this EJB adding the `@Interceptors` annontation like in this other SO question ([CDI Extensions - Add Interceptors in ProcessAnnotatedType phase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34474592/cdi-extensions-add-interceptors-in-processannotatedtype-phase))

I think the CDI Extension only executes after the EJB are already registered because the Interceptor is never called.

But, for test purpose I have successfully register and execute an Interceptor programmatically in a simple CDI Bean.

The problem is when I'm try to register in a EJB.

Am I missing something?

Edit:
I'm using Wildfly 8

Answer (score 2):

I think the key problem here is the difference between **`@Interceptors`** (EJB ones) and **`@Interceptor`** (CDI ones). CDI does not govern EJB container hence adding the EJB annotation (`@Interceptors`) in CDI extension won't necessarrily kick EJB logic into effect - EJB container might have started at that moment and it won't know of the annotation. Furthermore the CDI extension would add this annotation to the `AnnotatedType` which is a structure EJB probably won't make use of. On the other hand, all this really depends on the application server as it is responsible for CDI/EJB integration hence as a "bonus" the behavior might differ between AS.

CDI extension is something which allows you to hook into CDI bootstrap lifecycle, therefore you are able to use/enable/add CDI interceptors. I would try going that way instead. BTW even the [SO question you referred to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34474592/cdi-extensions-add-interceptors-in-processannotatedtype-phase) speaks of `beans.xml`/`@Priority` for enablement which means it uses **CDI interceptors** and not EJB ones.

Also, an EJB bean should automatically become CDI bean therefore you can attach CDI interceptor to it without changing the bean itself.